# How to call all imports like numpy , pandas and matplotlib inside one function?

Tags: python, python-3.x

I want to define all the imports like numpy, pandas, matplotlib and keras in a function and call it

When I try with numpy alone, I am getting the result, but not with others.

This is the code which I tried with numpy:

```
    #importing numpy module 
    # it is equivalent to "import numpy" 

    def imports():

        np = __import__('numpy',globals(), locals(), [], 0)
    imports()
    a=np.array([1,2,3])
    print(a)
```

Comment: your example will not work; it will leave `np` undefined in the line `a=np.array([1,2,3])`...

Comment: You can declare `np` as `global` in your function, that way you could access it outside the function scope.

Answer (score 0):

The problem with your example is [variable scope](https://www.datacamp.com/community/tutorials/scope-of-variables-python). Read on that stuff in the link, it's important to know. You can gogle additional resources easily.

You can fix your example with declaring `np` as a `global` variable, it can be done like this:

```py
>>> def imports():
    global np
    np = __import__('numpy',globals(), locals(), [], 0)


>>> imports()
>>> np
<module 'numpy' from 'C:[…]\\Python36\\site-packages\\numpy\\__init__.py'>
```